# ModelState.IsValid difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ObjectModelValidator and System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

We have upgraded our project from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 6 and with the changes we went from using `System.Web.Mvc` model validation to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding` object model validator.

Now when a customer wants to complete its purchase journey, they cannot get to the paying page because another page that - from the looks of it - has nothing to do with their payment page has a mandatory field that is not filled in.

In code we have a `PaymentController` with its view model and class / model; and let's call it an unrelated controller with its view model and class / model. These view models inherit from the same view model C.

Before the upgrade `ModelState.IsValid` in `PaymentController` would only validate the `Payment` view model where is now it is also validating the unrelated view model (we have many more controllers / view models / models, it does not apply to those).

The code for controllers, view models and their classes (models) remained the same.

Please help me figure this one out.

```
public class CViewModel<TPage> : ICViewModel<TPage> 
    where TPage : IContent
    public TPage CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public Core.Models.Pages.UnrelatedPage UnrelatedPage { get; set; }
    public GlobalSettingsPage GlobalSettings { get; set; }

public class PaymentViewModel : CViewModel<Core.Models.Pages.PaymentPage>, IPaymentViewModel    

public class UnrelatedViewModel : CViewModel<Core.Models.Pages.UnrelatedPage>

public class PaymentController : BasePageController<Core.Models.Pages.PaymentPage, PaymentViewModel>
{
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Core.Models.Pages.PaymentPage currentPage)
    {       
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewModel.IsEditPage = true;
                return View("/Features/PaymentPage/Index.cshtml", ViewModel);
            }

            return View("/Features/PaymentPage/Payment.cshtml", ViewModel);
        }            
    }
}

public abstract class BasePageController<TPage, TViewModel> : BaseAnyContentController<TPage, TViewModel>
    where TPage : PageData
    where TViewModel : ContentViewModel<TPage>, new()
{
}
```

Perhaps worth mentioning that View Model C has a property of the Unrelated class/type. That class contains the required property which is not filled in and validation of which fails the `PaymentController`.
BUT I tried to reproduce the same with another class. I added a new property to the C View Model of a 4th class, then went to it's View Model, added a Required tag, tested if now ModelIsValid would have a new error but it did not.

Comment: You could try ModelState.Remove method to remove the field you don't want to valididate

Comment: If it's not your requirement,please add some codes related

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I cannot use Remove method as there would be too many properties. I do not want the entire additional view model to be validated and anything that will be added to it in the future.

Comment: It is not the entire UnrelatedPage that comes as a null, but one out of million properties in it.------The incorrect inheritance caused plenty of unnecessary properties in your viewmodel

Comment: so just redesign your view model so that it could match your view